# jQuery - Pulling cell data from a table

Tags: jquery, html-table, row, cell

I need some help pulling cell data from table when a user clicks the an button at the end of the table row. The table is generated via Ajax technique.  I'm not sure if this makes a difference when accessing elements of the table.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script> 
  <p>** click me **</p>
  <br/>
  <div id="placeHolder">some text goes here!</p>
<script>
    $("p").click(function () { 

        $.ajax({
          url: "status_2.html",       
          cache: false,
          success: fnSuccess
          }
        );
    });

   function fnSuccess(msg)
    {
        $('div#placeHolder').html(msg);
    }

function selectEditActivity(pass_id){   
    var row = $('#'+pass_id); 
    var seq = row.attr('seq');      
    // here I would like to pull the value of the date from the selected row
    // but I just can't get syntax right.  I get a null value on alert
    var from_date   = $('td', row).eq(0).html();  
    alert(from_date);
}
</script>
```

This is the html code that gets read in (file: status_2.html)

```
  <span id="status2"> 
  <span id="response" class="response"></span>

  <table class="tableBorder">
  <tr >
   <th class="align_left">Date</th>
  </tr><tr>

  <tr seq="1" class="row_theme2" id="id3014201105191"></tr>
    <tr><td>20090519</td>
    <td>1330</td>
  <td>1430</td>
  <td>LUNCH</td>  
   <td></td>
   <td><a onclick="selectEditActivity('id3014201105191');" href="#">EDIT</a></td>
 </tr>

  <tr seq="2" class="row_theme2" id="id3014201105192"></tr>
    <tr><td>20100519</td>
    <td>1330</td>
  <td>1430</td>
  <td>LUNCH</td>  
   <td></td>   
   <td><a onclick="selectEditActivity('id3014201105192');" href="#">EDIT</a></td>
 </tr>

  <tr seq="3" class="row_theme2" id="id3014201105193"></tr>
    <tr><td>20110519</td>
    <td>1330</td>
  <td>1430</td>
  <td>LUNCH</td>  
   <td></td>   
   <td><a onclick="selectEditActivity('id3014201105193');" href="#">EDIT</a></td>
 </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
var from_date = $('td', row).eq(0).html();
```

to this:

```
var from_date = row.next().children('td').eq(0).html();
```

...because the information you're looking for is in the next row over from the one with the ID. The row with the ID has no `<td>` elements.

**Live Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkP56/

---

**EDIT:** You could get rid of the inline onclick handlers and let jQuery assign the handlers if you wanted.

```
$(function() {

    $('table tr a').click(function() {
        var from_date = $(this).parent().prevAll().last().html();
        alert( from_date );
    });

});
```

Comment: brillant! I always have problems with this type of example.  Is there a better way of expressing this solution?

Comment: @bob's your brother: Are you asking if there's a better way to accomplish this? If so, you may want to consider having jQuery handle your event handlers. You can get rid of the inline onclick handlers, and just traverse around the DOM from the one that was clicked. I'll give an update,